# Travis Swift: Suppress warnings from pod compile step

Tags: ios, swift, travis-ci

Over the last day I've been struggling with getting my iOS (Swift) project to pass the build and archive step.
The current issue is that the build never passes the compile step and I can't figure out why as the logs are always truncated.
It takes lots of time for the build to actually error out and most of the output are warnings from 3rd party libraries.

I'm using `xcpretty-travis-formatter` already but it seems to be hiding warnings only from objective-c pods. The pods written in swift are still spamming the output heavily. The last pod the build ever reached is RxSwift or RxDataSources.

Here's the list of the pods I've got in the project - maybe you had issues with any of them before:

`pod 'Mixpanel'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'RxSwift', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'RxAlamofire'
pod 'RxDataSources', '~> 0.5'
pod 'SwiftValidator', '3.0.3'
pod 'WillowTreeScrollingTabController'`

This is the command I'm using for the archiving step:

`` xcodebuild archive -archivePath "build" -workspace "my-project.xcworkspace" -scheme "my-project" -configuration Release | xcpretty -f `xcpretty-travis-formatter` ``

I'm looking for any pointers on what to try to reduce the time to compile the pods and get the build output to not fill up travis logs.